# Everything going on with somebody

Tags: phrase-requests

If you're continuously posting news about what someone is doing,  including their latest projects, is it correct to say (in the description of a fansite, for example):

> updates on everything going on with her

Is there a better way to express the concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you've got a target idiom in mind, but, if so, I don't recognize it.  In humdrum English, "there are updates on everything that's going on with her" / "on everything she's doing"

Comment: So a short and informal description like: "Photos, videos and updates on everything going on with her" would sound ok?

Comment: @Barbara: Yes, it would.

Answer (score 4):

A better (more professional, IMHO) phrase might be

> Updates on her current activities

If you want to sound more comprehensive, perhaps something like:

> Complete updates on all of her current activities

Comment: @Barbara: I guess that depends on the fans (and the object of their adoration)! ;)